# Tensorflow: TypeError while creating a custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras, multilabel-classification

I have a multilabel classification problem which i am solving with a tensorflow neural network:

```
epoch_count = 100
batch_size = 512
hidden_units = 19
eta = 0.1

# Define the model architecture
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(X_train.shape[1], activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)),
    keras.layers.Dense(hidden_units, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=WeightedCrossEntropy(positive_weights=positive_weights, negative_weights=negative_weights),
              metrics=[
                  Precision(name='precision'),
                  Recall(name='recall'),
                  BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy')
              ])

# Train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=epoch_count, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

Following a tutorial ([Imbalanced Multilabel Scene Classification using Keras](https://medium.com/the-owl/imbalanced-multilabel-image-classification-using-keras-fbd8c60d7a4b)) I tried to create a custom loss function with custom weights.

```
positive_weights = {}
negative_weights = {}
for c in label_vector[:, 0].astype(int):
    positive_weights[c] = merged_data.shape[0]/(2*np.count_nonzero(merged_data[c] == 1))
    negative_weights[c] = merged_data.shape[0]/(2*np.count_nonzero(merged_data[c] == 0))
    
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
        loss = 0.0
        loss -= (positive_weights[424]*y_true[0]*tf.math.log(y_pred[0]) + negative_weights[424]*(1-y_true[0])*tf.math.log(1-y_pred[0]))
        loss -= (positive_weights[7]*y_true[1]*tf.math.log(y_pred[1]) + negative_weights[7]*(1-y_true[1])*tf.math.log(1-y_pred[1]))
        loss -= (positive_weights[402]*y_true[2]*tf.math.log(y_pred[2]) + negative_weights[402]*(1-y_true[2])*tf.math.log(1-y_pred[2]))
    
        return loss
```

I also tried a different approach for the loss function with the following code but I get the same TypeError which I can't fix:

```
class WeightedCrossEntropy(tf.keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, positive_weights, negative_weights, epsilon=1e-7, name="weighted_cross_entropy", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.positive_weights = positive_weights
        self.negative_weights = negative_weights
        self.epsilon = epsilon

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, self.epsilon, 1 - self.epsilon)
        loss =- (self.positive_weights[424] * y_true[0] * tf.math.log(y_pred[0]) + self.negative_weights[424] * (
                    1 - y_true[0]) * tf.math.log(1 - y_pred[0]))
        loss -= (self.positive_weights[7] * y_true[1] * tf.math.log(y_pred[1]) + self.negative_weights[7] * (
                    1 - y_true[1]) * tf.math.log(1 - y_pred[1]))
        loss -= (self.positive_weights[402] * y_true[2] * tf.math.log(y_pred[2]) + self.negative_weights[402] * (
                    1 - y_true[2]) * tf.math.log(1 - y_pred[2]))
        return tf.math.reduce_mean(loss)

    def get_config(self):
        config = {
            'positive_weights': self.positive_weights,
            'negative_weights': self.negative_weights,
            'epsilon': self.epsilon
        }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {**base_config, **config}
```

0.875 is the value in positive_weights:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\BuyOrBurnTensorflow\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file9u5ymrga.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
    ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_file2x61h4sy.py", line 11, in tf__call
    loss = -(ag__.ld(self).positive_weights[424] * ag__.ld(y_true)[0] * ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).math.log, (ag__.ld(y_pred)[0],), None, fscope) + ag__.ld(self).negative_weights[424] * (1 - ag__.ld(y_true)[0]) * ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).math.log, (1 - ag__.ld(y_pred)[0],), None, fscope))
             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
TypeError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\BuyOrBurnTensorflow\venv\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\BuyOrBurnTensorflow\main.py", line 167, in call  *
        loss =- (self.positive_weights[424] * y_true[0] * tf.math.log(y_pred[0]) + self.negative_weights[424] * (

    TypeError: Expected int64, but got 0.875 of type 'float'.

python-BaseException

Process finished with exit code -1073741510 (0xC000013A: interrupted by Ctrl+C)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to cast y_true as a float.

```
y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
```